# How can i add shapes between photos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am beginner in bootstrap , i try to make photo galleries to my example website.I want to add the diamond shapes you see in the photo between the picture gallery.

I found this source code

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/urunler" target="_self" class="banner lazy ">
                <img src="" class="b-lazy b-loaded" width="397" height="397" alt="Dörtlü Banner">
                <div class="hover-diamond"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="split-left-diamond"></div>
            <div class="split-top-diamond"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/urunler" target="_self" class="banner lazy ">
                <img src="" class="b-lazy b-loaded" width="397" height="397" alt="Dörtlü Banner">
                <div class="hover-diamond"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="split-left-diamond"></div>
            <div class="split-top-diamond"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/urunler" target="_self" class="banner lazy ">
                <img src="" class="b-lazy b-loaded" width="397" height="397" alt="Dörtlü Banner">
                <div class="hover-diamond"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="split-left-diamond"></div>
            <div class="split-top-diamond"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/urunler" target="_self" class="banner lazy ">
                <img src="" class="b-lazy b-loaded" width="397" height="397" alt="Dörtlü Banner">
                <div class="hover-diamond"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="split-left-diamond"></div>
            <div class="split-top-diamond"></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

They use split diamond class but i cant reach the content which it includes. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? First, we gave the position `position-relative` in column class `col-xs-6` then we make the shape and its set position using CSS property like `transform` and `position`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/wrn5a8sk/2/